# Is there ability to get uploading BackgroundTransferRequest's result?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-transfer

I'm using `BackgroundTransferRequest` in WP8 application for uploading a file to my server. The server receives the file and send a response back with some useful info regarding uploaded file. How can I get this info?

It seems there's no API for that (shamely). Probably, I'm missing something.

**Note** that `request.BytesReceived` property returns 99 bytes, looks like request knows that some data is returned from server, but I've no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the great help of [Eric Fleck form MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/be5322f0-2c81-4b81-b5d4-c21bc9f78b12/is-there-ability-to-get-uploading-backgroundtransferrequests-result) we found out that adding `DownloadLocation` and `Method="Post"` properties making response to be written in `DownloadLocation` file. So the valid request is:

```cs
var request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(targetUri)
    {
        DownloadLocation = new Uri(downloadTo, UriKind.Relative),
        UploadLocation = new Uri(uploadFrom, UriKind.Relative),
        Method = "POST"
    };
```

Comment: shusha hi, I'm having the same situation as yours. server returns some jSon data after file upload successfully. I want to get that data. here as you said, I saw that `BackgroundTransferRequest` shows that `BytesReceived`. here I tried by assign `DownloadLocation` to get that data. but somehow it seems like Downloaded data is not copying into the file in IsolatedStorage `Shared/Transfers` folder.    Plz guide me further if possible..

Comment: @KevalLangalia make sure you actually have `/shared/transfers` part in your paths

Comment: I detected the issue. it was of unSuccessful request i resolved it and got the response. Thanks for your efforts.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are two events you can subscribe to, `TransferStatusChanged` and `TransferProgressChanged` (see MSDN [BackgroundTransferRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) page). Would these provide the information you're looking for?

There is also an example ["How to implement background file transfers for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that shows a way to display transfer information for multiple transfers.

Comment: I've already studied each and every line in MSDN regarding Background Transfers in WP8 - there's nothing helpful for my question. Also those events have nothing to do with uploading result as their names state.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question. What is this "useful info" that is sent back? Did you grab the response from Fiddler or something similar?

Comment: In the response to my POST upload request server returns and Id of the file. I have an implementation for this using `HttpClient` and its API allows to read the response content, but I want to use `BackgroundTransferService` instead.